# Gridview refresh issues with Umbraco nodes

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, user-controls, umbraco

I have a fairly straight forward Gridview which pulls in a set of Umbraco nodes. I am binding it on page load.

My issue comes up on the RowCommand to remove a program(node). The code to remove executes fine. The program(node) gets removed from Umbraco. Yet, no matter what I try, I can't get the GridView to refresh properly. The removed entry is still available.  Only a hard browser refresh clears it.

A databind after the processing was not cutting it. A redirect back to the page was not either. I've tried a permanentRedirect, which works sometimes, but not all.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPrograms" runat="server" CssClass="styledTable"
        AllowPaging="true" 
        PageSize="5"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        OnPageIndexChanging="gvPrograms_PageIndexChanging"
        onrowcommand="gvPrograms_RowCommand" 
        onrowdatabound="gvPrograms_RowDataBound">

       <rowstyle backcolor="White"  
       forecolor="#006296"
       font-italic="false"/>

      <alternatingrowstyle backcolor="#dbeef9"  
      forecolor="#006296"
      font-italic="false"/>

        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Program Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProgramDate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server" Text="Remove"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

 protected void gvPrograms_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit Program")
    {
        PopulateProgram(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        displayPanels(pnlAddProgram);
        hdrEdit.InnerText = "Edit Program";
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "Remove Program")
    {
        int id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

        //remove node from umbraco
        Document d = new Document(id);
        //umbraco.library.UnPublishSingleNode(id);
        d.delete();
        umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache(d.Id);
        umbraco.content.Instance.RefreshContentFromDatabaseAsync();
        umbraco.library.RefreshContent();

        lblMsg.Text = "The program has been successfully removed!";
        lblMsg.Visible = true;

        Response.RedirectPermanent("/chapter-tools/chapter-management-center/chapter-content-admin/programs-list.aspx");
        //BindData(programsNodeID);
    }
}

private void BindData(string programsNodeID)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    Node programsNode = new Node(Convert.ToInt32(programsNodeID));
    dt = programsNode.ChildrenAsTable();

    gvPrograms.DataSource = dt;
    gvPrograms.DataBind();

    if (gvPrograms.Rows.Count > 0)
        lblNone.Visible = false;
    else
        lblNone.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I've had the same kind of issue when doing an import while checking existing items based on the nodeFactory. I thought I noticed a slight delay (1 or 2 seconds) after adding/removing an item and the update of the umbraco.config. Maybe this is what you experience...

Comment: Possibly. But I have to figure out a work-around as this makes for a pretty awful user experience.

Comment: @JGrimm, What does your data-binding code look like?

Comment: Added BindData method to the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try unpublishing the node first before deleting it, as is suggested by [Munkimagik’s technical Blog](http://munkimagik.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/deleting-documentnode-from-umbraco/).

```
Document d = new Document(id);

if(d.Published)
{
    d.UnPublish();
    umbraco.library.UnPublishSingleNode(d.Id);
}

d.delete();
umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache(d.Id);
```

Comment: Tried this out of the gate. Unfortunately, doesn't cure my problem.